# Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../". When running on live-server

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps

I'm receiving an error of `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "leaflet". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"`

I'm trying to run my app with [Live-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server) package.

I'm using Google Chrome as a browser, I'm enabling CORS, cause otherwise I will receive a CORS related error.

The error pointing me on a first line of this code

```
    import "./styles.css";
import L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

const icon = L.icon({
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [10, 41],
  popupAnchor: [2, -40],
  iconUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6/dist/images/marker-icon.png",
  shadowUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6/dist/images/marker-shadow.png"
});

var map = L.map("map", {
  preferCanvas: true
}).setView([51.505, -0.09], 3);

L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  attribution:
    '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

fetch("https://gbfs.urbansharing.com/oslobysykkel.no/station_information.json")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {
    console.log(responseData.data);
    const stations = responseData.data.stations;

    const layerGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

    stations.forEach(({ lat, lon, name, address }) => {
      layerGroup.addLayer(
        L.marker([lat, lon], { icon }).bindPopup(
          `Name: ${name}, Address: ${address}`
        )
      );
    });

    map.fitBounds(layerGroup.getBounds());
  });
```

But I'm pretty sure that it's something with this -

```
import L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
```

This is my `package.json`

```
    {
  "name": "oslotest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "node": "^14.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

As you can see I have `leaflet` installed via NPM.

When I run this code in sandbox - there is no problem at all.

[Demo Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/displaying-json-data-on-leaflet-map-forked-jhhuz?file=/package.json)

Comment: Run the site using `npm start` instead. Works for me. edit: wait: the codesandboxes' package.json is different, it uses parcel; you cannot use installed modules with live-server directly. You can use `import` in modern browsers, but you need to add `type="module"` to your script and import from online packages.

Comment: @ChrisG I'm sorry but can you explain more about type="module" and where I suppose to use it?

Comment: Don't go down that rabbit hole, just replace your package.json with the one from the codesandbox, run `npm install` then `npm start`

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you so much, that help's me out!